# Utility for viewing Chrome-trace-format JSONs

Tags: gratis, software-development, chrome, utility, profiling

Chrome/ium has a trace viewing functionality, accessible via `chome://tracing`, which can load trace files in a certain JSON format and display them along a timeline. This is nice, but - I would like to be able to do that without a behemoth web browser. Is there a smaller trace viewer utility I could use?

Requirements:

- Gratis
- Runs in Linux desktop environments
- Small memory footprint
- Fast

Desired features:

- Libre
- Actively developed
- Multi-platform